# What is the "long description" field on a Facebook page? Is it publicly viewable? If so, where?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I help to manage a Facebook page. We've filled in the "short description" field, and it's visible on our Facebook page's About tab. We've also filled in the "long description" field, but I wasn't able to figure out where the contents of this field were made visible to the public. Can the public see the contents of the field? If so, where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I temporarily logged out of Facebook, in order to experiment and discover the answer.

A page's About tab is divided up into sub-tabs, which may include "Overview", "Page Info", and/or "Milestones".  For example, the [Facebook page for Fog Creek Software](//www.facebook.com/fogcreeksoftware/info?tab=overview) includes both "Overview" and "Page Info".

I thought that the "Page Info" sub-tab was visible only to me, a page administrator, and was used only for modifying page settings and data.  I was therefore hoping that the long description would be shown somewhere on the "Overview" sub-tab.

But I was wrong.  It turns out the "Page Info" sub-tab *is* actually visible to the public; they simply see fewer fields.  But they do indeed see the contents of the "long description" field right there on that sub-tab.

So it turns out that quite a few clicks are required for the user to see the contents of the "long description" field.  If you prefer, you can instead describe your company or product in a pinned post on its page's timeline; that way, more users will see your words.